# How can design a dynamic seat planner?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a code that can prepare a seating plan with the seat information I got from the database. I record the seats in the database as follows;

```
public class seat
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int row { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public int authorium_id { get; set; }
    }
```

Reserved seats are as follows

```
public class seat_reserved
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int seat_id { get; set; }
        public int reservation_id { get; set; }
        public int screening_id { get; set; }

    }
```

While researching on Google, I think the plugin in the following URL would work

[jQuery Seat Charts](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts)

But I am developing it in .net environment and I can not dynamically edit the code block below

```
var sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
                map: [
                    'aaaaaaaaaa',
                    'aaaaaaaaaa',
                    '__________',
                    'aaaaaaaa__',
                    'aaaaaaaaaa',
                    'aaaaaaaaaa',
                    'aaaaaaaaaa',
                    'aaaaaaaaaa',
                    'aaaaaaaaaa',
                    'aa__aa__aa'
                ],
...
```

How do I organize the seats in the Map section via the database?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create array of the sheets and it serialize to json and assign it to it,

Suppose you have defined an array with seets

```
 class SeatSelectionViewModel{
       public List<string> seets{get;set;}
 }
```

javascript

```
      var sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
            map: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.seets)),
```

Note: This is just an idea you need to thin about concrete solution with your project need

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think each element has a single string for your idea. I must able to change each char, but json is good idea.

Comment: @UmutGür exactly you need to design a model for your required json